# How exactly to do Responsiveness on Android?

Tags: android, checkbox, responsive-design, android-linearlayout, responsiveness

By developing a simple screen, and putting a simple text and putting two check boxes to test, as you can see:

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/fTCpBp0
I'm showing the image through another website, just because I'm not able to upload the image to this website, ok?
Sorry about that, but it's really necessary to show.

It is not even possible to move the checkboxes. That is, the checkboxes do not move. Please how to fix?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/corDeFundo"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoDosSintomas1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="453dp"
        android:text="Testing Responsiveness on Android"
        android:textColor="@color/corPreta"
        android:textSize="80px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:textSize="80px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:textSize="80px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not sure i understand, what do you actually want to happen ?

Comment: Why would you expect checkboxes to move?  They check and uncheck.  Phone apps aren't like web browsers, you don't get to resize them horizontally and have to respond to that, so that definition of "responsive" doesn't exist here. (When people talk about responsiveness in phone apps, they mean does the UI respond quickly to input).

Comment: "you don't get to resize them horizontally and have to respond to that" -- technically, you do. Landscape split-screen, foldables, and freeform multi-window all would support resizing horizontally. "When people talk about responsiveness in phone apps, they mean does the UI respond quickly to input" -- FWIW, I sometimes see "responsiveness" in the context of supporting varying screen sizes, though more often across devices (e.g., phones and tablets). I agree that the term is overloaded.